# Export data from Data table to Access database c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a data-table and I want to update access database table. So, I have written a code as following.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
// table has some data...
OleDbConnection db_conn1 = new 
OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + source);
db_conn1.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); 
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = db_conn1;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.Connection = db_conn1;
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
for (int i = 0; i <= (table.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
{
     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO access_table(Id, " + table.Columns[0].ColumnName.Trim() + ") VALUES (" + (i + 1) + ",'" + table.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0) + "')";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     for (int j = 1; j <= (table.Columns.Count - 1); j++)
     {
          cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE [access_table] SET [" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.Trim() + "] = @add WHERE [Id] = @add1";
          cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add",table.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(j));
          cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add1", (i+1));
          cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
Id        Name
 1         A
 2
 3
 .
 .
 N
```

But in second column I am getting value only for single time. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Clear your parameters at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding parameters to your command object, so try clearing them:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= (table.Columns.Count - 1); j++)
{
  cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE [access_table] SET [" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.Trim() + "] = @add WHERE [Id] = @add1";
  cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add",table.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(j));
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add1", (i+1));
  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more efficient just to INSERT and then not to UPDATE, by adding all of the fields to the INSERT statement.  You can do so like this:

```
using (var db_conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + source))
{
    db_conn1.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = db_conn1;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        string firstSQL = "INSERT INTO access_table(Id";
        for (int i = 0; i <= (table.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            string midSQL = ") VALUES(" + (i + 1).ToString();

            StringBuilder colNames = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder valParams = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 1; j <= (table.Columns.Count - 1); j++)
            {
                colNames.Append(", " + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.Trim());
                string paramName = "@add" + j.ToString();
                valParams.Append(", " + paramName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, table.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(j));
            }
            cmd.CommandText = firstSQL + colNames.ToString() + midSQL + valParams.ToString() + ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I have also included the OleDbConnection and the OleDbCommand in using sections.  This is recommended practice as both implement IDisposable.  Doing this means that the Garbage Collector ("GC") knows that it can safely dispose of the objects after use - and data connections use a lot of resources, so it is always good to clean then as soon as possible.